# Why can't file columns have a third dimension?

Tags: database, file

I am writing code that handles large amounts of data each second.
I was going to use this method: essentially every time-period, usually around 30 seconds, around 3,000 files create a new column in a *.csv* file containing 3 entries. Is there anyway to condense this into one file with a "third dimension" for each file.

[An example of one file with the program running for 3 time periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llmzX.png)

I'm imagining the data being 3D as that is the best way to describe it. Any help or questions are welcome.